# How to put through attributes inside association attributes with Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do some complex query with Sequelize in my express API. What I need done is to get the Stage with its Users, but with the user remaining budget, which is an attribute on a pivot table between the two models, but I need it flat.

Here are the simplified models:

Stages:

```
class Stages extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init(
          { stageName: DataTypes.STRING },
          { sequelize },
        )
    }
    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsToMany(models.Users, { foreignKey: 'stageId', through: 'StageUsers', as: 'users' })
    }
}
```

Users:

```
class Users extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            userName: DataTypes.STRING,
            userPhoto: DataTypes.STRING,
        }, {
            sequelize
        })
    }
    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsToMany(models.Stages, { foreignKey: 'userId', through: 'StageUsers', as: 'involvedStages' })
    }
}
```

StageUsers (pivot table):

```
class StageUsers extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            userTotalBudget: DataTypes.FLOAT,
            userRemainingBudget: DataTypes.FLOAT,
        }, {
            sequelize
        })
    }
    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.Stages, { foreignKey: 'stageId', as: 'stage' })
        this.belongsTo(models.Users, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user' })
    }
}
```

Now, this is my query so far:

```
Stages.findByPk(stageId, {
    include: [
        {
            association: 'users',
            attributes: ['id', 'userName', 'userPhoto'],
            through: { attributes: ['userRemainingBudget'] },
        },
    ],
})
```

So, my expected output is this:

```
{
    id: x,
    stageName: x,
    users: [
        id: x,
        userName: x,
        userPhoto: x,
        userRemainingBudget: x,
    ]
}
```

And my actual output is this:

```
{
    id: x,
    stageName: x,
    users: [
        id: x,
        userName: x,
        userPhoto: x,
        StageUsers: {
            userRemainingBudget: x,
        }
    ]
}
```

I couldn't find something useful here nor on GitHub nor on the docs. Can you help me correct this output? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yoiu can try `attributes: ['id', 'userName', 'userPhoto', [Sequelize.col('StageUsers.userRemainingBudget'), 'userRemainingBudget']]` but  I'm not sure it will work. Please try it.

Comment: @Anatoly Unfortunately, it returns " Unknown column 'users.StageUsers.userRemainingBudget' "

Comment: Another way is to define associations to and from `StageUsers` and include them and indicate their single attribute `userRemainingBudget` along with all needed attrubutes from `User` uing `Sequelize.col`